# Calculate Cost Deviation

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

How to calculate Deviation of work and cost of each task on MS project 2010.

There is any option for finding the report of Standard deviation.

How to find "Cost Deviation" in MS project 2010.

Is it possible to calculate "Cost Deviation" of single task or machine.

Comment: Project is a scheduling tool...  I assume that "cost deviation" is "cost variance"...You could estimate cost for every work package, then record actual cost; cost deviation would then be estimated-actual.    The calculation is simple; the tool makes it complex.  And I'm not sure what the value of "cost deviation" for a single task or machine would be...

Answer (score 1):

MS Project automatically calculates those values in the "Work Variance" and "Cost Variance" fields, as far as your project has a saved baseline.

To save a baseline, use the command located in the "Project" tab.

Once you have a baseline, the mentioned fields will calculate automatically when a task is updated and some values are different from the baseline ones (for example, a longer task).

The calculation is made at task level.

Hope this help. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

As Francesco stated, you have specific fields for that. You need a baseline of course but I would add, even if it sounds stupid or obvious, that you also need all your ressources rated to allow calculation

Answer (score 0):

Do it manually with a calculator. The formula is: Real costs - calculated cost = Cost deviation.

A friend of mine uses MS Project and says it's no good. He works in a small company and he says that it costs quite a lot and it just complicates things. He said it would be more efficient if they wrote Post-It notes and exchanged them instead of clogging the workflow with MS project. But maybe that's just him.

Comment: Welcome to PMSE. Would you mind adding more detail as to how/why MS Project is "no good"?

Comment: @Sarov The mentioned friend of me works i, a small company and he says that it costs quite a lot and it just complicates things. He said it would be more efficient if they wrote Post-It notes and exchanged them instead of clogging the workflow with MS project. But maybe that's just him.